# What is the best way to group data pairs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Instead of using associative arrays (objects), what is the best way to associate two values so they are always associated and can both be accessed as separate values? Associative arrays are annoying because their order isn't guaranteed and you can't access them using indexes.

I could create two separate arrays but if I randomize their order for display their association would not match, and if they are separate in code there is a good chance I can make a mistake when recording their values, putting them in the wrong order so they don't perfectly match up.

Comment: We need code. Its unclear why 2d arrays or objects wont work..

Comment: For index-like behavior you could use something like `.c0`, `.c1`, and `['c' + i]`..

Comment: Well, it depends. You can still an array of `{ key, value }` elements, but it's apparently a bad choice for huge lists. BTW, can't you just create another value for views, based on the main one, but not tightly-coupled to it?

Comment: Also, if you care about order, why not just use regular arrays? as in `[x, y]` ?

Comment: Are you saying objects with named keys are associative arrays? Have you tried using an array of arrays of fixed size?

Comment: @bryc hey, that's not a bad idea. Didn't think about that.

Comment: I voted to close this question as it asks for *the best way to group data pairs* based on some vague statements, so this is rather a guessing game than an answerable question.

Comment: Question is vague, are you referring to Map object ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you can use multidimensional arrays:

```
var data = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
];

data[0][0]; // get '1'
data[0][1]; // get '2'
```

Also if you need to associate data in a more abstract way, ES6 has [WeakMaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap):

```
var wm = new WeakMap();
var x = document.createElement("div");
wm.set(x, {foo: 1, bar: 7});

console.log(wm.get(x).bar) // get '7' from object you associated to HTMLElement
```

Comment: Thanks! Even though my question is for some reason getting down voted and closed, this answer gave me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I do not now which kind of data you should store but maybe you could try to store data in a single variable in this way:

```
var data = [];

data[0] = "Test" + "|" + Value;
```

Comment: Unless of course the data *contains* "|"

Comment: I mean it's not the worst idea but then I'd have to search within the array value and then parse it.

Comment: *Its the worst idea

Comment: Whit a delimiter the parsing is very simple in javascript.

Comment: Any other idea guys? Whitout using a 2d array or two separate array?